# SQL return rows if matches keywords

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a large list of strings (outside of a PostgreSQL database), and I want to go through that list of strings (in a loop) and want to check to see if any part of the string belongs in a table.

For example, I have the two following tables:

```
table name: trigger_keyword
id (int)
keyword (text)
```

and table 2:

```
table name: trigger_message
id  int
message text    
trigger_keyword_id int /*this is a fk to id on trigger_keyword */
```

Let's assume we have key word "weather good" in the `trigger_keyword` table, and we have a message in `trigger_message` linked to the id of that keyword.

so below is an example of how things look in our tables

trigger_keyword table

```
id                             keyword
-----------------------------------------------------
1    weather good
```

trigger_message table

```
id   message                   trigger_keyword_id
-----------------------------------------------------
1    yes, the weather is good  1
```

in one of our strings outside of the SQL database we have the following sentence

"is the weather good in Alaska?"

What SQL can I write to return "yes, the weather is good" because "weather good" is in our `trigger_keyword` table? do I need to use `LIKE` for this? I only need help with the SQL portion.

Comment: You can make the problem (and the sql-statement) more simple if you add the trigger-message as a extra field to the trigger-keyword table.

Comment: @split, but I will have multiple messages for each keyword in the `trigger_keyword` table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like you should use full text search:

```
SELECT m.message
FROM trigger_keyword AS k
   JOIN trigger_message AS m ON k.id = m.trigger_keyword_id
WHERE to_tsvector('english', 'is the weather good in Alaska?')
      @@ phraseto_tsquery('english', k.keyword);
```

Comment: thanks, it does work, but I have another keyword "how are you" in the `trigger_keyword`  and when I change `to_tsvector('english', 'is the weather good in Alaska?')` to `to_tsvector('english', 'how are you today?')` no rows are returned

Comment: Then you should use the `simple` text search configuration rather than `english` - that has no stop words.

Comment: very interesting, I will have to do some reading on to_tsvector

Comment: What do you think is the best setup if we want to have multiple keywords for messages? For example, in the key table we have "climate", "weather", "humidity", etc.. but we want to link to them by one ID (not multiple rows)  and we have a few messages that have FK to the same keywords. If this is possible I can create a new question for it.

Comment: Your present setup is the best one; it is normalized. Don't consider using arrays.

Comment: but let's say I want to use the same message for two different keywords. For example we have these keywords ("hi" and "hello") and we want to have "hey how are you" and "hey how are you doing?" for both of those keywords, in the current setup I would have duplicate data since I would have to create those messages twice and point them to "hi" (using FK) once and create them again and set their FK to "hello" What do you think?

Comment: Then have three tables: one for keywords, one for messages and one that connects them.

Comment: I created a third table https://pastebin.com/daeM1jP8  https://i.imgur.com/nCEj9gD.png  it's my first time using a bridge table, should I have update on cascade set?  In this third table I manually enter the related rows right?

Comment: I think so. But I'd say let's stop this here - ask another question when in doubt.

Comment: thanks, I will start a new question with all the new details

Comment: I made a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545225/full-text-search-on-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184497/discussion-between-arya-and-laurenz-albe).