# Full text search on many to many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables

[image]

The keywords table

```
CREATE TABLE trigger_keyword
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    keyword text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT trigger_keyword_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

This is the bridge table

```
CREATE TABLE trigger_keyword_trigger_message
(
    trigger_keyword_id bigint NOT NULL,
    trigger_message_id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT trigger_keyword_trigger_message_trigger_keyword_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (trigger_keyword_id)
        REFERENCES public.trigger_keyword (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT trigger_keyword_trigger_message_trigger_message_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (trigger_message_id)
        REFERENCES public.trigger_message (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

The message table

```
CREATE TABLE trigger_message
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    message text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT trigger_message_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I have a list of strings outside of the PostgreSQL database, which I will run in a loop.

Let's assume we have the following keywords in the `trigger_keyword` table

The trigger_keyword table

```
id  keyword
----------------------------------------
1   hi
2   hello
3   the weather
4   the climate
```

The trigger_message table

```
id  message
-----------------------------------------
1   Hi how is your day?
2   Hello, have a wonderful day
3   Looks sunny today
4   Excellent, no rain today
5   looks like we'll have showers today
```

Let's say one of our strings is `Hi Robot!`, then the SQL query should return `Hi how is your day?` or `Hello, have a wonderful day`; it should pick one of them randomly. It should do the same if the string contained `hello robot` instead of `hi robot` since both `hi` and `hello` are in the keywords table.

And if the string contains `tell me the weather` then the SQL query should return `Looks sunny today` or `Excellent, no rain today` or `looks like we'll have showers today` randomly.

I assume I would have to use full text search for this?

It's my first time using a bridge table, do I manually insert the relations in the bridge table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a primary key constraint on the “bridge” table that contains both columns.

Full text search as indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53532377/6464308) is one way to do this.

To randomly pick one result row, you can append the following to the query:

```
ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1
```

To insert into the tables, you could use a `DEFAULT` clause with a sequence in the definition of the `id` columns and use `INSERT ... RETURNING` to get the values for the bridge table.